# Picture CSS Transition issue

Tags: html, css, animation, transition, slide

I have a slide that transitions between four pics. I have the slide going at a certain pace, but the last slide does not transition back to the first slide quickly. I have tried to add another nth and I have tried to slow down the last nth, but it doesn't work. I want the whole slide to transition at a certain time but the last slide needs to go back to the first without the huge black delay I am getting. Here is the code:

```
    .picTransition .item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: picTransition 56s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: picTransition 56s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: picTransition 56s linear infinite;
  animation: picTransition 56s linear infinite;
}
.picTransition .item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.picTransition .item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
  animation-delay: 24s;
}
.picTransition .item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 36s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 36s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 36s;
  animation-delay: 36s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes picTransition {
    0%, 25%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
    4.17%, 20.84% { opacity: 1;}
}
@-moz-keyframes picTransition {
    0%, 25%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
    4.17%, 20.84% { opacity: 1;}
}
@-ms-keyframes picTransition {
    0%, 25%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
    4.17%, 20.84% { opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes picTransition {
    0%, 25%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
    4.17%, 20.84% { opacity: 1;}
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 4 images and you set

```
animation-delay: 12s;
```

for each one, the cicle time is 4 * 12 = 48s.

Instead, you have a cycle time of 56s

```
animation: picTransition 56s linear infinite;
```

That means a 8 seconds gap a the end

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Thanks for you assistance. I forgot I had 56s. DETAILS. Thanks!